# FFMpeg merge video and audio at specific time into another video

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp4

I have a standard mp4 (audio + video)
I am trying to merge a 1.4 second mini mp4 clip into this track, replacing the video for the length of the mini clip but merging the audios together at a specific time

Would anyone know how to do this using ffmpeg?

I've tried quite a few different filters, however can't seem to get what I want

```
                          V <------->
miniclip.mp4              A <=======>
             V <----------->  ↓ + ↓  <--->
standard.mp4 A <=========================>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example to show `miniclip.mp4` (1.4 seconds long) at timestamp 5.

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -i miniclip.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]drawbox=t=fill:enable='between(t,5,6.4)'[bg];[1:v]setpts=PTS+5/TB[fg];[bg][fg]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:eof_action=pass;[1:a]adelay=5s:all=1[a1];[0:a][a1]amix" output.mp4
```

- *drawbox* covers the main video with black. Only needed if `miniclip.mp4` has a smaller width or height than `main.mp4`. You can omit it if `miniclip.mp4` width and height is ≥ than `main.mp4`. Alternatively you could use the *scale2ref* filter to make `miniclip.mp4` have the same width and height as `main.mp4`.
- *setpts* add a 5 second offset to `miniclip.mp4` video.
- *overlay* overlays `miniclip.mp4` video over `main.mp4` video.
- *adelay* adds a 5 second delay to `miniclip.mp4` audio.
- *amix* mixes `miniclip.mp4` and `main.mp4` audio.

#### More info

- See [FFmpeg Filter Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) for info on each filter.
- [How to get video duration](https://superuser.com/a/945604/)

Comment: Hey, so if I remove the drawbox for now and get this:
-filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=5s:all=1[a1];[0:a][a1]amix" output.mp4

I get the error:
Optional all not found 
Error initializing filter 'adelay' with args '5s:all=1'

If I remove all=1, I just get the miniclip at the start, nor does it replace the video, any ideas?

Comment: @LugIa Your ffmpeg is too old.

Comment: Absolute genius thank you!
When adding multiple miniclips, it massively reduces the audio quality - Would you know how to fix this? or possibly merge multiple clips into one command?

Comment: so ultimately your command works great, I just use a python script to iterate at slight different time frames until I have a 'complete video' with multiple mini-clips in. Just with the poor audio quality

Comment: I have tried quite a few different options with things like -acodec copy, and various -crf settings although nothing seems to maintain audio quality - any ideas?

Comment: @LugIa Share some input files and your command so I can try it and better understand what the problem is.

Comment: So I am cutting multiple clips from an mp4, this is using python and lots of different points - Using the -crf 16 option to try and get a good video/audio quality (which seems to work fine)
I am then looping through all these clips, and merging them into the main video.mp4 (30-100 clips in total) however after about 10 clips being merged the audio becomes distorted. I am using your command, and then when the output.mp4 video from it is main, renaming it back to main.mp4 ready for the next loop
Haappy to provide more code if needed?

Comment: @LugIa Show a command I can try to duplicate the problem.

Comment: The command is:
os.system("ffmpeg -y -i main.mp4 -i  "+counter+"clip.mp4 -filter_complex \"[0:v]drawbox=t=fill:enable='between(t," + start_time + ","+ end_time + ")'[bg];[1:v]setpts=PTS+"+start_time+"/TB[fg];[bg][fg]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:eof_action=pass;[1:a]adelay=" + start_time * 1000 + "m:all=1[a1];[0:a][a1]amix\" output.mp4")
sleep(2)
os.system("mv output.mp4 main.mp4 -f")

I've tried using one clip, and inserting that clip 30 times and I still get it - If you want I can generate some code for you to insert 30 clips, every 1 second in a 1 minute video?

Comment: @LugIa Just give me an unscripted ffmpeg command that I can copy and paste.

Comment: ffmpeg -y -i main.mp4 -i clip1.mp4 "[0:v]drawbox=t=fill:enable='between(t,1,2)'[bg];[1:v]setpts=PTS+5/TB[fg];[bg][fg]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:eof_action=pass;[1:a]adelay=1s:all=1[a1];[0:a][a1]amix" output.mp4

this is the command, then move output.mp4 to be main.mp4 - change the timings for each iteration :)
Just like to say again, thanks so much for helping me with this

Comment: @LugIa It seems like you are re-encoding the same file over and over. This results in [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss) which causes reduced quality.

Comment: Interesting that would make sense, is there any way in which this can be mitigated to maintain as high as quality as possible?

Comment: Or would doing it in one command be better? I've tried something like this:
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -i that.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]drawbox=t=fill:enable='between(t,5,5.5)'[bg];[1:v]setpts=PTS+5/TB[fg];[bg][fg]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:eof_action=pass;[1:a]adelay=5s:all=1[a1];[0:a][a1]amix" -i that.mp4  -filter_complex "[0:v]drawbox=t=fill:enable='between(t,6,6.5)'[bg];[1:v]setpts=PTS+6/TB[fg];[bg][fg]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:eof_action=pass;[1:a]adelay=6s:all=1[a1];[0:a][a1]amix"  output.mp4
(many more times over) although this doesn't quite get the result I expect

Comment: @LugIa Stack Overflow is a little different than discussion forums. You're expected to ask 1 question. Constant follow-up questions are discouraged. Instead you can make a new post with the new question. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thats understandable, thanks @llogan. Posted a new question here, as others using this ffmpeg command may also have this issue! [ffmpeg-reduce-generation-loss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68818232/ffmpeg-reducing-generation-loss-when-inserting-many-videos-into-another-video)

Answer (score 0):

Edited (now I understood the question):

```
First Get 1.4 seconds of standard.mp4 and audio1.mp3
```

-ss is the start for get the small video that will be 1.4 seconds of length (with -t option you can specify the duration, in this case 1.4 seconds) summary: cut video from min 5, 1.4 seconds
-an is for audio none copy, because you want to add a new audio1.mp3

video_only.mp4

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:05:00 -i standard.mp4 -t 1.4 -map 0:v -c copy -an small_only_video.mp4
```

---

audio_only.mp4

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:05:00 -i audio1.mp3 -t 1.4 -c copy small_only_audio.mp3
```

now you can to create a small_clip_audiovideo.mp4

```
ffmpeg -i small_only_video.mp4 -c:a mp3 -i small_only_audio.mp3     -c copy -map 0:v -map 1:a:0   -disposition:a:0 default  -disposition:a:1 default  -strict -2 -sn -dn -map_metadata -1 -map_chapters -1  -movflags faststart small_clip_audiovideo.mp4
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I would want the audio1.mp3 to be an mp4, and replace the standard.mp4 video at 1.4 seconds for the length of the small clip, would you know how to do that?

Comment: Thanks @Stevejobs for the help so far, so I believe this will get the video from one, audio from the other, then combine the two? I'm looking to combine the audios from both, and replace the video from the standard.mp4 with the mini clip, so for the duration of the mini clip replace the video of the main mp4, but merge the audios, I can give an example if needed?

Comment: I've updated the main post to hopefully make more sense, would be greatly appreciated any response :)

Answer (score 0):

```
                          V <------->
miniclip.mp4              A <=======>
             V <----------->  ↓ + ↓  <------->
standard.mp4 A <=============================>

               |--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|
               0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  

           standard.mp4 have 10 seconds (aprox) of duration, have audio and video

           miniclip.mp4 have 03 seconds (aprox) of duration, have video and audio

ffmpeg -i standard.mp4 |
                        } have same codes of video and audio?*
ffmpeg -i miniclip.mp4 |
```

- if are not a same  audio code or video code of files standard.mp4 and miniclip.mp4,   you will be to recode for continue, if you want a good work.

ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -i standard.mp4 -t 4 -c copy 01.part_project.mp4

- and 7 to 10, in 03.part_project.mp4

  ffmpeg -ss 00:00:04.000 -i standard.mp4 -t 3.0000 -c copy 03.part_project.mp4
- changue name or create a copy of miniclip.mp4 to 02.part_project.mp4

  cp miniclip.mp4 02.part_project.mp4

(the part of 4 second to 7 seconds, of standard.mp4 will be used if you choice the OPTION 2 copy only the audio, santadard_part2_audio.mp4)

NOW THE OPTION N 1: IS TO CONTACT (UNITED) the 3 video parts

make a folder "option1" and copy 01.part_project.mp4 02.part_project.mp4 03.part_project.mp4

```
mkdir option1 && cp 01.part_project.mp4 02.part_project.mp4 03.part_project.mp4 ./option1 && cd ./option1
```

now you concat 01.part_project.mp4  +  02.part_project.mp4  +  03.part_project.mp4 into a unique file fin_option1.mp4

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in ./*.mp4; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) -c copy fin_option1.mp4



                          V <------->
miniclip.mp4              A <=======>
             V <----------->  ↓ + ↓  <------->
standard.mp4 A <============XXXXXXXXX========>

               |--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|
               0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

---

- THE  SECOND OPTION IS TO CONTACT (UNITED) the 3 video parts, BUT MIX
  THE AUDIO OF miniclip.mp4 with santadard_part2_audio.mp4

  get the audio stream from santadard_part2_audio.mp4 and get the audio
  file only from miniclip.mp4

  ffmpeg -i santadard_part2_audio.mp4 -map 0:a -c copy -vn -strict -2 mix_audio_santadad.mp4

---

```
ffmpeg -i miniclip.mp4 -map 0:a -c copy -vn -strict -2 mix_audio_miniclip.mp4
```

---

MIX ALL AUDIOS** IN ONE AND PUT THE VIDEO FROM miniclip.mp4

---

```
ffmpeg -i mix_audio_miniclip.mp4 -i mix_audio_santadad.mp4 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest -strict -2  audio_mixed_miniclip.mp4
```

---

get only video from miniclip.mp4

---

```
ffmpeg -i miniclip.mp4 -c copy -an miniclip_video.mp4
```

---

and get miniclip but with mixed audios, I think that it is the solution that you are looking for

---

```
ffmpeg -i miniclip_video.mp4  -i audio_mixed_miniclip.mp4   -c copy -map 0:v -map 1:a:0  -disposition:a:0 default  -disposition:a:1 default  -strict -2 -sn -dn -map_metadata -1 -map_chapters -1  -movflags faststart 02.part_project_OPTION2.mp4 




                     santadard_part2_audio.mp4  
                           + 
                        audio_miniclip.mp4

                          V <------->
miniclip.mp4              A <MMMMMMMM> (audio miniclip mixed with standard.mp4)
             V <----------->  ↓ + ↓  <------->
standard.mp4 A <============         ========>

               |--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|
               0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

make a folder "option2" and copy 01.part_project.mp4 02.part_project_OPTION2.mp4 03.part_project.mp4

mkdir option2 && cp 01.part_project.mp4 02.part_project_OPTION2.mp4 03.part_project.mp4 ./option2 && cd ./option2

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in ./*.mp4; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) -c copy fin_option2.mp4

NOTES
** YOU CAN USE A LOT OF AUDIO MANIPULATIONS https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation

Comment: Trying to work out this, so this blanks out the video in the main, then adds the other over the top?