# FFMPEG reducing Generation Loss when inserting many videos into another video

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am trying to insert many miniclips.mp4 into a main.mp4 video - Although I have been able [to do this using this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68445013), I seem to suffer from Generation Loss

The command I am using (within a python script, in a loop at many different intervals) is:

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -i miniclipX.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]drawbox=t=fill:enable='between(t,5,6.4)'[bg];[1:v]setpts=PTS+5/TB[fg];[bg][fg]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:eof_action=pass;[1:a]adelay=5s:all=1[a1];[0:a][a1]amix" output.mp4
```

(Then renaming output.mp4 to main.mp4 within a loop)

Would there be anyway to either:

A) Reduce generation loss by implementing certain flags

or

B) Include many different input files and many different -filter_complex's in a singular command to achieve what I am after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you did not provide the ffmpeg log (and therefore there is no info about your ffmpeg or your inputs), for this answer I'll assume all videos are the same width and height.

Example to show `miniclip1.mp4` at 5 seconds and `miniclip2.mp4` at 10 seconds:

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -i miniclip1.mp4 -i miniclip2.mp4 -filter_complex 
"[1:v]setpts=PTS+5/TB[offset1];[0:v][offset1]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:eof_action=pass[bg];
 [2:v]setpts=PTS+10/TB[offset2];[bg][offset2]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:eof_action=pass;
 [1:a]adelay=5s:all=1[a1];
 [2:a]adelay=10s:all=1[a2];
 [0:a][a1][a2]amix=inputs=3"
output.mp4
```

Command was broken into multiple lines so it is easier to read. Make it one line when executing.

Comment: I see for the 2nd filter complex you moved the [0:v] and [bg] around - what would need to be done for a 3rd, 4th, etc input? As something this gives me errors:
`ffmpeg -y -i main.mp4 -i c1.mp4 -i c2.mp4 -i c3.mp4 -filter_complex "
[1:v]setpts=PTS+3.0/TB[offset1];[0:v][offset1]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:eof_action=pass[bg];
[2:v]setpts=PTS+3.5/TB[offset2];[bg][offset2]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:eof_action=pass;
[3:v]setpts=PTS+4.5/TB[offset3];[bg][offset3]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:eof_action=pass;
[1:a]..[a1];
[2:a]...[a2];
[3:a]..[a3];
[0:a][a1][a2][a3]amix=inputs=4" out.mp4
`

Comment: @LugIa Not sure what errors you're getting. Do not reuse filter label names. `ffmpeg -y -i main.mp4 -i c1.mp4 -i c2.mp4 -i c3.mp4 -filter_complex " [1:v]setpts=PTS+3.0/TB[offset1];[0:v][offset1]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:eof_action=pass[bg]; [2:v]setpts=PTS+3.5/TB[offset2];[bg][offset2]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:eof_action=pass[bg2]; [3:v]setpts=PTS+4.5/TB[offset3];[bg2][offset3]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:eof_action=pass; [1:a]..[a1]; [2:a]...[a2]; [3:a]..[a3]; [0:a][a1][a2][a3]amix=inputs=4" out.mp4`

Comment: The error I am getting (when trying to add a third input for example )is:
`Invalid stream specifier: bg3...<rest of my command>. matches no streams`
I am getting this if I iterate the bg for each input - iterating the offset seems to work, but not the bg? Thanks again for the help @llogan

Comment: @LugIa Need to see your command to understand the problem.

Comment: My command is: `ffmpeg -y -i m.mp4 -i c1.mp4 -i c2.mp4 -i c3.mp4 -i c4.mp4-filter_complex "
[1:v]setpts=PTS+2/TB[offset1];[0:v][offset1]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:eof_action=pass[bg];
[2:v]setpts=PTS+3/TB[offset2];[bg][offset2]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:eof_action=pass[bg2];
[3:v]setpts=PTS+4/TB[offset3];[bg3][offset3]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:eof_action=pass;
[4:v]setpts=PTS+5/TB[offset4];[bg4][offset4]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:eof_action=pass;
[1:a]a....[a1]; [2:a]....; [0:a][a1][a2][a3][a4]amix=inputs=5" out.mp4`
with this it doesn't like the other bgX

Comment: @LugIa You telling overlay to use `[bg3]` as an input, but you never made anything named `[bg3]`. The label names can be arbitrary. You could use just about any label you want, but it must exist. `[bg3]` does not exist in your command.